# Next.Js Framer-motion trouble

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web, next.js

When i use a framer-motion in my component i get this type of error
What it could be?
Server Error
Error: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
eval
node_modules\framer-motion\dist\es\context\MotionConfigContext.mjs (6:42)
(rsc)/./node_modules/framer-motion/dist/es/context/MotionConfigContext.mjs
file:///C:/Users/lifec/OneDrive/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC/wifionnext/.next/server/vendor-chunks/framer-motion.js (310:1)
**webpack_require**
file:///C:/Users/lifec/OneDrive/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC/wifionnext/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js (33:42)
eval

I tried to reinstall react, framer-motion. I have all imports

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the framer to 4.1.*, I knew in November the latest version was causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

For Next 14 : Use `"use client"` in the file where you are using framer-motion

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
```